# a reverse of foamToVTK tool?

Tags: openfoam, error-estimation

my question is simple, in openfoam we have the function foamToVTK which creates vtk files for each timestep of the solution.

Now I have a huge VTK tar file (has atleast 100 timesteps), i have system 0 and constant folders can we convert those vtk files back to time folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today, there is no officially released functionality in OpenFOAM versions that converts VTK data to OpenFOAM grid data. Yet, a heuristically written python script was provided for such purposes: [herein](https://github.com/edwardsp/VTKToFoam).

Comment: Good stuff, I don't need it anymore but I will try it out.